# Need to create jar file for the compiled clojure classes

Tags: clojure

I am learning clojure and already got an assignment.

I need to automate compile and build jar of the classes generated.

Within the clojure code, I need to compile another clojure code,  write code to build the jar of the classes generated.

Here is my example.

even_test.clj

```
(ns clojure.sqe.examples)

(defn pair-test [test-fn n1 n2]
(if (test-fn n1 n2) "sucess" "failed"))

(println (pair-test #(even? (+ %1 %2)) 3 4)) ; -> pass
```

compile_test.clj

```
(ns clojure.sqe.examples
    (:use clojure.test)
    (:require [simple-check.core       :as sc])
)

(compile 'clojure.sqe.examples.even_test)
;(println *compile-path*) => classes

;TO-DO - Write code to
;Build the jar for the compiled classes or from classes folder

; upload this jar to a service .
```

Comment: Ditto on using leiningen. It simplifies quite a bit of your development, and it's a very good tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to 1. compile the code and then 2. create a JAR file containing the compiled code.

Clojure's [`compile`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/compile) function compiles code and puts the compiled class files (there can be more than one) under the directory specified by `*compile-path*`.

You will need to create a JAR file using [JarOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarOutputStream.html) (and optionally a [Manifest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/Manifest.html)), and write all the files under `*compile-path*` into the JAR.  You will have to massage the paths so that a file like `target/repl/classes/clojure/sqe/examples.class` is put into the JAR as  `clojure/seq/examples.class`.

The `lein jar` command more or less does this, so you might want to look at its source code for details: https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/src/leiningen/jar.clj

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use [Leiningen](http://leiningen.org/)? It is the de facto for doing Clojure development. You can do a lot of things, such as compiling Clojure sources, compiling Java sources, run unit tests, generate POM files from porject.clj and of course, generating JAR files.

> lein jar
>   Package up all the project's files into a jar file.
>
> lein uberjar
>   Package up the project files and all dependencies into a jar file.

Comment: Updated my post.  I have to write a code to build the jar within the clojure code compile_test.clj